Can we configure settings like max concurrency for each function inside Azure function app
I want to add configuration for individual functions which are in single azure function app.
All the documentations says that we can only configure at function app level using host.json
Thanks in advance!
I tried with custom attributes in c# but it is not working

The unit of deployment is what's scaled out/in. Function App is the unit of deployment. Therefore, to scale out individual functions, you'll need to break those out into individual Function Apps.
